# Компилируется файл .a вместо .lib в windows

Tags: c++, mingw

я использую компилятор MinGW, пытаюсь собрать .lib файл, но почему то собирается .a
на другом устройстве с windows собирается .lib. в выводе сборки не нашел никаких упоминаний расширения. как мне сделать так, чтобы собирался .lib?

Comment: Зачем? `.a` - родное расширение MinGW/GCC. В `.lib` собирает MSVC.

Comment: если я захочу подключить статическую библиотеку к другому проекту в windows, разве мне понадобится не .lib?

Comment: Что вам понадобится - зависит от того, чем вы будете компилировать другой проект. Если MinGW - то `a`, если msvc - то `lib`. Главное - чтобы и статическая библиотека, и основной проект компилировались одним и тем же компилятором.